# Passing variable in multiple github repositorues using github action's workflow

Tags: docker, github, kubernetes, workflow

Hi so I am new to the `GitHub` actions and I wanted to deploy a multi-environment application into the EKS cluster I have multiple repositories.

`Repo 1:` Application repo that will do a `docker build` & `push` with a tag as `GitHub SHA`

`Repo 2:` Manifest `YAML` repo which will consist of deployment yamls for the above application

I want to send the TAG through which the docker images were pushed and update the TAG in the deployment `YAML`.

I'm not sure how to do it so was not able to try anything
Can anyone please help..?
Thanks in advance :)

Update :
I found a document
http://blog.marcnuri.com/triggering-github-actions-across-different-repositories/
So I can use following curl command

```
curl -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/dispatches \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.everest-preview+json' \
-u $your_user:$your_personal_access_token \
--data '{"event_type": "$your_event", "client_payload": { "customField": "customValue" }}'
```

To send the Value to other repo but I wanted to know what are the security risks involved by using the CURL command and will it be in best practice to use this approach.

Comment: Did you look at the [Docker and Github Action for Kubernetes CLI](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/kubectl-aws-eks)?

Comment: Yes I looked actually issue is that one repo will do docker build and push the image in JFROG repo and second repo will consist of all the yamls for application like deployment & service and I wasted the tag value to be pulled from repo1 and use it in repo2